# adding items into sublist of list based on condition in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 2 lists like below

```
list1=[['a',2,3],['b',4,5],['c',6,7]]
list2=[['a',5],['b',3],['c',8]]
```

i want to join this 2 list as 1 list based on the condition on sublist.
if 1st element of sublist in list1 is equal to 1st element of sublist in list2, then 2nd element of sublist in list2 should add to list1

here result should be

```
list1=[['a',2,3,5],['b',4,5,3],['c',6,7,8]]
```

i am able to do it for single list item like below

```
list1=['a',2,3]
list3=['a',5]

if list1[0]==list3[0]:
   list1.extend(list3[1:])
else:
   list1
print list1
```

help me the same in doing for sublist as mentioned above.i am unable to apply 2 for loops.

help me

Comment: help me even the list2 like this list2=[['a',5],['c',8],['b',3]].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest to convert the main list to a dict:

```
dict1 = { e[0]:e[1:] for e in list1 }
print(dict1)
#=> {'a': [2, 3], 'c': [6, 7], 'b': [4, 5]}
```

Then iterate over `list2` adding elements to the dict:

```
for e in list2:
  dict1[e[0]].extend(e[1:])
#=> {'a': [2, 3], 'c': [6, 7], 'b': [4, 5]}
```

If you need it back as a list (to be sorted):

```
result = [ [k] + v for k, v in dict1.items() ]
print(result)
#=> [['a', 2, 3, 5], ['c', 6, 7, 8], ['b', 4, 5, 3]]
```

Answer (score 4):

This is your initial data:

```
>>> list1=[['a',2,3],['b',4,5],['c',6,7]]
>>> list2=[['a',5],['b',3],['c',8]]
```

Then, we [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) your lists and we use list comprehension to generate a new list:

```
>>> [ a+b[1:] for a,b in zip( list1, list2 ) if a[0] == b[0] ]
```

Results:

```
[['a', 2, 3, 5], ['b', 4, 5, 3], ['c', 6, 7, 8]]
```

Just in one line of code :)

**Edited 1**

> thanks but its not working if the list2=[['a',5],['c',8],['b',3]]. Help me

```
>>> list1=[['a',2,3],['b',4,5],['c',6,7]]
>>> list2=[['a',5],['c',8],['b',3]]  # <--- other list2
```

Using `if` in different place:

```
>>> [ a+ ( b[1:] if a[0] == b[0] else [] )  for a,b in zip( list1, list2 ) ]
```

Results:

```
[['a', 2, 3, 5], ['b', 4, 5], ['c', 6, 7]]
```

**Edited 2**

> but the 2nd and 3rd sublist in list1 has values in list2 but its not arranged in sequence as list1.

Sorting before zip.

```
>>> zipped_sorted_list = zip( sorted(list1), sorted(list2) ) 
>>> [ a+ ( b[1:] if a[0] == b[0] else [] ) for a,b in zipped_sorted_list ]
```

Results

```
[['a', 2, 3, 5], ['b', 4, 5, 3], ['c', 6, 7, 8]]
```

Comment: thanks but its not working if the list2=[['a',5],['c',8],['b',3]]. Help me

Comment: but the 2nd and 3rd sublist in list1 has values in list2 but its not arranged in sequence as list1.

Comment: @learningstudent, I guess you should to post desired results samples on your post.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1=[['a',2,3],['b',4,5],['c',6,7]]
list2=[['a',5],['b',3],['c',8]]
#Sort the lists by first element in each sublist
list1.sort(key=lambda x: x[0]) 
list2.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
#this count is used with the next loop in order to keep track of comparison 
#between list1's sublists with list2's sublists.
count = 0 
for sublist in list1:
    if sublist[0] == list2[count][0]: #comparison logic here
        sublist.extend(list2[count][1:])
    count += 1 #increment the count each loop
print (list1)
```